# How to print without the image

Tags: graphics, document-classes, plot, printing

I want to print a document without print the images too: just the position of them so the printer make the process faster (I have some big image and i don't want to spend ink and time to print them).

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: you can do this by setting `\documentclass[draft]{report}` or `book` or `article` or whatever documentclass you are using.  Just make sure to use the `draft` option

Comment: Also check out the ``endfloat`` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by using the documentclass option `draft`.  E.g.:

```
\documentclass[draft]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Hello.  This is my picture

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{myfilename}
\caption{Figure's Caption}\label{fig:figuresample}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Also, as stated by Sverre, you can always check the [`endfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package, which seems to have some other options to leave a space where the figure would be.